# How can we make pandoc produce pretty, human readable HTML from markdown?

Tags: html, css, vim, pandoc

Recently I realized that I had made a bad choice by writing my notes in Markdown. I wanted to switch to HTML instead and put it on my website.

I used pandoc for converting the file from html to markdown:
`pandoc file.md -o file.html`

But everything seems wrong about this (snippet from vim):

[image]
Problems:

1. Code is not readable. It was very, very readable in Markdown, but I'm not sure what's up with character codes showing up instead of something humans can read.
2. Indentation is weird. I just did indentation with the usual `gg=G` in vim, and it seems that all the `<p>` tags are being gradually indented further and further to the right. Is this expected behaviour? It certainly looks ugly.
3. Specific things about the HTML code are undesirable. This is probably the least vexing, since you can easily replace things with substitute, but since I am planning on using prism for code highlighting, I would like things like `class="language-c++"` instead of `class="sourceCode cpp`.

Question: Is there any way to easily fix up this mess, or have pandoc generate better in the first place? Is there a substitute that works better than pandoc? Is there a pandoc option that I am missing?

Comment: make sure you use the newest pandoc version from https://pandoc.org/installing.html (I don't get the `<p>` indentation), you can pass the output of pandoc to `htmltidy` or similar, to do substitution best to use a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)

Answer (score 3):

By "character codes" I assume you mean `&gt;` and the like.  These are necessary in HTML, since a `<` character has a special meaning.  Without these escapes you'd have invalid HTML.

Indentation:  pandoc does not indent its HTML output.  So this is the result of something you did in vim.  It's not a pandoc issue.

Code formatting:  By default, pandoc inserts classes and span tags to create highlighted HTML for code blocks.  If you don't want this (e.g. if you want to do your own highlighting with some JavaScript code) then you can disable it using `--no-highlight`.  You may still get some transformation of class names.  You can change these using a simple lua filter: see the documentation for [lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html).